# Join a substring to a table from another database

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to do a n inner join by creating a new column using substring to match it with another column in a database so to display the name in the other table

The code is

```
SELECT  
    REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(flh[FIleName]), 0, CHARINDEX('_', REVERSE(flh[FileName])))) AS FILENAMES,
    SUBSTRING(flh.[Filename], 0, LEN(flh.[FileName]) - CHARINDEX('_', REVERSE(flh.[FileName])) + 1) AS DATE,
    erc.DisplayName    
FROM 
    [Recon_E].[ETL].[tblFileLoadHistory] flh 
INNER JOIN 
    Feed.dbo.tblEnfusionReRunConfig erc on  flh.filenames = erc.FileName
WHERE
    flh.RecRunId = (SELECT MAX(RecRunId) 
                    FROM Recon_E.etl.tblFileLoadHistory)
```

I'm separating the date and the string in the SubString Select.

But I'm not able to give the alias filename to the new column and perform the join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to use Common Table expressions or CTEs like below if you are on SQL 2005 or later.

```
;with FileLoadHist as 
-- define cte query
( 
 SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(flh[FIleName]),0,CHARINDEX('_',REVERSE(flh[FileName]))    ))AS FILENAMES,
SUBSTRING(flh.[Filename],0, len(flh.[FileName]) - charindex('_',reverse(flh.[FileName])) +1) AS DATE
 FROM [Recon_E].[ETL].[tblFileLoadHistory] flh 
 where flh.RecRunId=( SELECT max(RecRunId) from    Recon_E.etl.tblFileLoadHistory   )
)
--define outer query
select FILENAMES, DATE, erc.DisplayName  
from  FileLoadHist 
INNER JOIN Feed.dbo.tblEnfusionReRunConfig erc on  FileLoadHist.FILENAMES =    erc.FileName
```